# How can I refactor this small piece of code so that I don't call a function inside render

Tags: react-native, refactoring

I read on this [page](https://codeburst.io/6-simple-ways-to-speed-up-your-react-native-app-d5b775ab3f16) that you should not create functions inside the render method.  One way around this is to bind.

My constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.idCheckAlert = this.idCheckAlert.bind(this);
}
```

The function I created:

```
idCheckAlert = (idForAPI) => () => {
//does some stuff with the idForApi 

}
```

Inside my render:

```
  <TouchableOpacity 
         style={styles.inputButton}
         onPress={() => { 
         const idForAPI = this.userId;
         this.idCheckAlert(idForAPI); 
         }}
    >
```

My current refactor looks like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
     style={styles.inputButton}
     onPress={this.idCheckAlert(this.userId)} 
>
```

However, I would like to instead create a variable inside onPress, but when I do I get an error message that says unexpected token.  Is there a way for me to create a variable inside onPress, without having to create a function?

Comment: The `refactor` code is not correct, you are calling `idCheckAlert` during render operation. Are you facing any issue by using the code before `refactor`? The code before `refactor` is aligned with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good practice create the variable inside onPress, just like you said, but you can do it after the render

```
const userId = 1;
return (
<TouchableOpacity 
     style={styles.inputButton}
     onPress={this.idCheckAlert(userId)} 
>
);
```

Comment: In a case for something like a TextInput, is it possible to avoid creating a function?  For example, if I had this inside my TextInput: onChangeText={(value) => {
                                this.verifyLengthOfId(value);
                                this.userId = value;
                            }}